# Altering schema in dockerized MySQL database

Tags: mysql, docker, liquibase

How is MySQL in Docker used in Production when updates are necessary.

For example, adding a column or table, etc.

Is there a way of using Liquibase?

Comment: It does not make any difference if the database is dockerized or on a physical machine. You always need to connect to MySQL using the server name or ip and the port. Liquibase and DB versioning tools in general, on the other hand, offer advantages like: keeping track of versions of your DB.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can run MySQL in a Docker container just like you'd run MySQL on a VM. Once deployed in a container, you can run any MySQL SQL via mysql client (or any client including JDBC) as long as you have the container running at a resolvable address and have the right credentials. The client doesn't know (or care) that your MySQL server is running in a container - all client cares about is the host, port, database and user/password values.

That said, you need to make sure you mount a volume for your container so that MySQL data can be "externalized" and you don't lose everything just because you ran a `docker rm`. With plain Docker, you can use the `-v` option to mount a voulme from the Docker host VM or an external disk (such as EBS or EFS/NFS). With Kubernetes, you can use a `statefulset` with a `persistentVolumeClaim` to make sure you preserve the storage no matter what happens to your container.

Comment: That i understand question is: :how revisions of database schemes are managed.. Such as adding tables etc. Login to the cluster and run SQL query? Or is there a better way

Comment: How would you do it on a "regular" MySQL installed on a VM or a host? You'd do the same for the container as well. You would login to MySQL using `mysql` client or via a JDBC client and run the script. You can use a SQL script, or any `mysql` specific commands via `mysql` client. You can also use Liquibase or Flyway or similar version manager frameworks. Or may be your question is still not clear to me.

Comment: The idea is to automate this process.. Maybe my question is misunderstood..Im looking for a way to automate the proces

Answer (score 0):

Mysql on docker acts mostly as an standalone Mysql installation. Be careful to configure a volume for the data or you will lose upon container restart or termination.

Said that, you can use any mysql consuming app, as you only need is to expose the port, and configure crendentials.

Comment: That i understand question is: :how revisions of database schemes are managed.. Such as adding tables etc. Login to the cluster and run SQL query? Or is there a better way

Comment: Is there any other way? Even if you se a database management software it will log in to the server and run commands. Once you expose (and secure) the proper ports, there is no difference on running standalone or with Docker.

Comment: The idea is to automate this process.. Maybe my question is misunderstood..Im looking for a way to automate the process